# Trying to understand Python code for linked list

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I am new to both OOP and data structures and would appreciate if someone could help me better understand the code below (linked list in Python). Specifically, I want to know what object type or class does "current" from append method belong to - is it Element or LinkedList? Since it is indented within LinkedList, I am inclined to believe it is a LinkedList. Second, is current.next accessing the "next" attribute of Element class? If yes, then how? Any clarity would be helpful. I have been able to follow more clearly other versions of linked list codes that would explicitly use an instance of Element class where "current" is used in this code, but I just can't seem to comprehend what is going on here.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def get_position(self, position):
        counter = 1
        current = self.head
        if position < 1:
            return None
        while current and counter <= position:
            if counter == position:
                return current
            current = current.next
            counter += 1
        return None

    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        counter = 1
        current = self.head
        if position > 1:
            while current and counter < position:
                if counter == position - 1:
                    new_element.next = current.next
                    current.next = new_element
                current = current.next
                counter += 1
        elif position == 1:
            new_element.next = self.head
            self.head = new_element

    def delete(self, value):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current.value != value and current.next:
            previous = current
            current = current.next
        if current.value == value:
            if previous:
                previous.next = current.next
            else:
                self.head = current.next



# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a LinkedList
ll = LinkedList(e1)
ll.append(e2)
ll.append(e3)

# Test get_position
# Should print 3
print(ll.head.next.next.value)
# Should also print 3
print(ll.get_position(3).value)

# Test insert
ll.insert(e4,3)
# Should print 4 now
print(ll.get_position(3).value)

# Test delete
ll.delete(1)
# Should print 2 now
print(ll.get_position(1).value)
# Should print 4 now
print(ll.get_position(2).value)
# Should print 3 now
print(ll.get_position(3).value)
```

Comment: Do you not have examples of this code's usage? I imagine you create `LinkedList` with an `Element`, so `self.head` would be an `Element`.

Comment: It presumably is whatever you pass in to the `LinkedList` constructor, and it seems to be expecting an `Element` object. "Since it is indented within LinkedList, I am inclined to believe it is a LinkedList." No, that doesn't really follow

Comment: "Second, is current.next accessing the "next" attribute of Element class? If yes, then how?" What do you mean how? By doing `current.next` - that is accessing the `.next` attribute on whatever `current` is

Comment: Nodes of the linked list are all `Element` objects. `LinkedList` is a wrapper that holds the reference to the first node in the list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What confuses me is that current seems to be a variable in LinkedList class but it accesses the next attribute from Element class, without there being a parent child relation between the two classes. But the code seems to work. What makes you say that it is expecting a Element object?

Comment: @wkl I have updated the code to include test cases. You are right about creating LinkedList using Element. Still the class of current variable is not obvious to me and I am wondering how can it access next attribute from another class.

Comment: Of course, you can *always* access an attribute of some object. Imagine you have inside some class definition: `x = list(); x.append(y)` turn you are accessing the `.append` attribute of the list class inside your own class. This is totally normal